# specify pocketsphinx language model or grammar

Tags: linux, grammar, pocketsphinx

On Debian I'm trying to launch `pocketsphinx_continuous` with this arguments:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -hmm /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -adcdev plughw:0,0 -dict /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic
```

Here the last part of the output:

```
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 137543 * 20 bytes (2686 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic
INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 1010 KiB for strings, 1664 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 133436 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 11 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: continuous.c(305): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: May 22 2016, AT: 22:01:16

ERROR: "pocketsphinx.c", line 957: No search module is selected, did you forget to specify a language model or grammar?
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 250: Failed to start utterance
```

I don't know how to specify the language model or grammar as requested.
i also have these files but I don't know if they are related:

```
ls -l ~/phonetisaurus/
totale 318644
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi       498 mag 15  2012 compile-fst.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  68172496 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.arpa
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   3544610 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.corpus
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  51190845 lug  4 08:49 g014b2b.fst
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 163490139 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.fst.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    380388 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.hyp
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      1223 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.isyms
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      1128 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.osyms
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    299283 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.ref
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  35625073 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.ssyms
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   3452982 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.train
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    101264 mag 15  2012 g014b2b.words
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      1327 mag 15  2012 README.txt
```

I read the documentation and the help provided launching the command without any arguments but I cannot understand what I'm actually missing.

EDIT:

as suggested I compiled from sources:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/5prealpha/sphinxbase-5prealpha.tar.gz
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha.tar.gz
```

For each file:

```
tar xzf <filename>
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To be sure it's installed:

```
which pocketsphinx_continuous 
/usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous
```

and:

> To check that pocketsphinx is installed properly, just run pkg-config –cflags –libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -L/usr/local/lib -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxbase -lsphinxad -lpulse -lpulse-simple -lpthread -lm
```

The tutorial says:

> To test installation, run 'pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes' and check that it recognizes words you are saying to the microphone.

But:

```
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 80: Acoustic model definition is not specified either with -mdef option or with -hmm
```

[full log: http://pastebin.com/HK6xBgVk ]

With this command I'm able to start it:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -hmm model/en-us/en-us -lm model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin -dict model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict -adcdev plughw:0,0
```

(without the adcdev field it cannot find the default audio input)

but it doesn't recognize any word (I was saying: "what's the weather like?")

[full log: http://pastebin.com/nfst5NQD ]

Comment: To avoid any question about my poor English I downloaded a file from here (http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/webcast/tae_betterspeaking_archive.shtml) and tried to recognize. Here few seconds of the file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4143780/test.wav. And here the full log: http://pastebin.com/CajqDhhd. By the way it takes 29 seconds to complete on RPi3.

Comment: It is not going to recognize large vocabulary speech in realtime on RPi3, it is too slow for that. You can relax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the outdated pocketsphinx packages from Debian, it is going to have zero accuracy anyway.

You need to install pocketsphinx from source as described in [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx)  and follow the tutorial further. To understand the models in speech recognition you can read [other part of tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialconcepts).

Comment: I followed the tutorial but when launching `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes` I get: `INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 80: Acoustic model definition is not specified either with -mdef option or with -hmm`

Comment: With the original command I get the same error (about language model)

Comment: You need to provide the full log. You can paste it to pastebin or share on dropbox/google drive and give here a link. Error is not the same. First is about acoustic model, second is about language model. To learn difference between them you need to read the tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial says: "To test installation, run 'pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes' and check that it recognizes words you are saying to the microphone." but it doens't work! The only way I found is: `pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 16000 -inmic yes -hmm model/en-us/en-us -lm model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin -dict model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict -adcdev plughw:0,0` but it recognize nothing. Here a full log: http://pastebin.com/nfst5NQD

Comment: Tutorial works if you follow it precisely with understanding of basic Linux things. In your case most likely you skipped make install, that's why I ask you for the log. In your second command you do not need -samprate and -plughw options. It also prints recognition results if you read the log.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a basic Linux knowledge and I properly compiled and installed from sources as stated in the manual. I update my question with further details.